# "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.The response had HTTP status code 403."

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have Angular products services and its calls  "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts" URL using the HttpClient method.

But, It displays the "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:5700' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 403."

As per my understanding from above error is need to set headers but its just public get API so, I think don't need to set the headers for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Public API or not, the headers still need set.

Comment: Can you supply a sample using https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's actually an error that's thrown by the browser and can only be fixed at the server-side. as you can see, the endpoint doesn't set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response headers, so you cant call it from any other domain inside a browser (in this case, `'http://localhost:5700`). it's headers are:

```
access-control-allow-credentials →true
cache-control →public, max-age=14400
cf-cache-status →HIT
cf-ray →3c4f9790845896e8-FRA
connection →keep-alive
content-encoding →gzip
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Tue, 28 Nov 2017 19:04:16 GMT
etag →W/"6b80-Ybsq/K6GwwqrYkAsFxqDXGC7DoM"
expires →Tue, 28 Nov 2017 23:04:16 GMT
pragma →no-cache
server →cloudflare-nginx
transfer-encoding →chunked
vary →Accept-Encoding
via →1.1 vegur
x-content-type-options →nosniff
x-powered-by →Express
```

Comment: Thanks GHB for your feedback its clarify my misconception :).

Comment: happy to help ;)